# Is there a generic linked list functionality for any structure

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have two structures in my code like this:

```
typedef struct Food {
    char* name;
    int food_id;
    int price;
    int capacity;
    int hall_id;
    int day;
    int reserved;
    int profit;
    Food* next;
} Food;

typedef struct Coupon {
    int id;
    int percentage;
    int capacity;
    Coupon* next;
} Coupon;
```

And I want to implement a linked list data structure with them. For example I have a `Food*` variable which points to food number 1 and then food number 2 in `next` points to the next food and...

The problem is when I want to write functions for the linked lists, I have to write 2 functions for every job. For example I want to have a function that gets the head of the list and a new element, then add the new element to the list. Because the types of these two linked lists are different, I can't think of a way to write only one function for both. Is there a way to do so?

For example I want to make this function work for all types:

```
void add_front(Coupon* head, Coupon* new_el){
    while (head->next != NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = new_el;
    new_el->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can invent your own, or use something like [utlist](https://www.cs.bu.edu/~jappavoo/Resources/psml/apps/hashy/uthash/doc/utlist.html).

Comment: Did you consider to use a `union` of pointers to the different data objects?

Comment: @utlist I don't want to use utlist and what do you mean by inventing your own? Because I want to write the functions by myself. the problem is I don't want to write one function for all structures.

Comment: @alilolo "_invent your own_": the guy who wrote utlist invented it. He invented his own.

Comment: @thebusybee I didn't know that. how can I do it?

Comment: you could use intrusive lists. Like one used in GIT itself. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/list.h

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us one example of such a function for us to work with. It could work for just one type, that's OK.

Comment: @thebusybee  I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible trick is to use the fact that it is legal to convert a pointer to a struct to a pointer to its initial member, and that it is legal to convert from any pointer type to void * and back. So provided `next` is the first member, a number of functions could be independant of the actual class, if they take `void *` parameters for any struct for which the first element is a `next` pointer. Of course, auxiliary function able to handle a real object should be provided...

Here is an example code showing a possible implementation of `add_before`, `add_after`, `list_remove` (`remove` is defined in `stdio.h`) and `display` and showing an example of use with `Coupon` objects:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Food {
    struct Food* next;
    char* name;
    int food_id;
    int price;
    int capacity;
    int hall_id;
    int day;
    int reserved;
    int profit;
} Food;

typedef struct Coupon {
    struct Coupon* next;
    int id;
    int percentage;
    int capacity;
} Coupon;

void* add_before(void* list, void* elem) {
    *(void **)elem = list;
    return elem;
}

void* add_after(void* list, void* elem) {
    if (NULL == list) return elem;
    void** last = list;
    while (*last != NULL) {
        last = *last;
    }
    *last = elem;
    return list;
}

// eltdisplay is a pointer to a function able to display an element
void display(void* list, void (*eltdisplay)(void*, FILE *), FILE *out) {
    while (NULL != list) {
        eltdisplay(list, out);
        if (NULL != *(void **)list) {
            fprintf(out, " -> ");
        }
        list = *(void **)list;
    }
    fprintf(out, "\n");
}

void* list_remove(void* list, void* elem, int(*comp)(void* elt1, void* elt2)) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    void** cur = list, **old = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (0 == comp(cur, elem)) {
            if (old == NULL) return *cur;
            *old = *cur;
            break;
        }
        old = cur;
        cur = *cur;
    }
    return list;
}

int couponcomp(void* elt1, void* elt2) {
    return ((Coupon*)elt1)->id != ((Coupon*)elt2)->id;
}

void coupondisplay(void* elt, FILE *out) {
    Coupon* coupon = elt;
    fprintf(out, "%d", coupon->id);

}
int main() {
    Coupon data[3] = { {NULL, 1}, {NULL, 2}, {NULL, 3} };
    Coupon* list = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data); i++) {
        list = addLast(list, data+i);
    }
    display(list, coupondisplay, stdout);
    Coupon data2 = { NULL, 2 };
    list = list_remove(list, &data2, couponcomp);
    display(list, coupondisplay, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with no warning and displays as expected:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
1 -> 3
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you separate the domain data of each entry from the managing data.

```c
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int food_id;
    int price;
    int capacity;
    int hall_id;
    int day;
    int reserved;
    int profit;
} Food;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int percentage;
    int capacity;
} Coupon;
```

Then you can use a union with *pointers* to the domain data in the entry's structure. Each entry will be of the same size.

```c
typedef struct Entry {
    struct Entry* next;
    union {
        Food* food;
        Coupon* coupon;
    } data;
} Entry;
```

You could even place the domain data directly in the union, but this will waste memory if only small sized values are stored.

```c
typedef struct Entry {
    struct Entry* next;
    union {
        Food food;
        Coupon coupon;
    } data;
} Entry;
```

Now you are able to add new entries of different data with a generic function.

```c
void add_front(Entry* head, Entry* new_el) {
    while (head->next != NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = new_el;
    new_el->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro :

From one of my personal project

```
#if !defined(CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST_H)
#define CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST_H

//T must include ->prev and ->next member
#define DECLARE_NAMED_CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST(T, name)  \
  static inline T* name ## _add_after(T* source, T* item) { \
    T* last_next = source->next;                            \
    source->next = item;                                    \
    item->prev = source;                                    \
    item->next = last_next;                                 \
    last_next->prev = item;                                 \
    return source;                                          \
  }                                                         \
  static inline T* name ## _add_before(T* source, T* item) {\
    T* last_prev = source->prev;                            \
    source->prev = item;                                    \
    item->next = source;                                    \
    item->prev = last_prev;                                 \
    last_prev->next = item;                                 \
    return source;                                          \
  }                                                         \
  static inline T*  name ## _remove(T* item) {              \
    T* next = item->next;                                   \
    item->prev->next = item->next;                          \
    item->next->prev = item->prev;                          \
    return next == item ? NULL : next;                      \
  }

#define DECLARE_CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST(T) DECLARE_NAMED_CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST(T, list_ ## T)

#endif // CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST_H
```

```
typedef struct Food {
    Food* next;
    Food* prev;
    char* name;
    int food_id;
    int price;
    int capacity;
    int hall_id;
    int day;
    int reserved;
    int profit;
} Food;

DECLARE_CIRCULAR_DOUBLE_LINKED_LIST(Food)

list_Food_add_after(Food*, Food*);
list_Food_add_before(Food*, Food*);
list_Food_remove(Food*);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way I ever found to do this in C (i.e., without templates) was:

1. Make a `SinglyLinkedNode` class that just has `SinglyLinkedNode *next`
2. Write your list functions based on this class -- every list is a list of `SinglyLinkedNode`
3. Add `SinglyLinkedNode node` fields to `Food` and `Coupon`, and use that to link them together.
4. Additionally provide functions or macros to get the containing `Food` or `Coupon` pointer from a `SinglyLinkedNode` pointer, like `Coupon *couponFromNode(Node *p);`

Note that I would never actually do this for singly-linked lists, because singly-linked list operations are so easy to write that you don't really need list methods.  This technique starts to get useful for doubly-linked lists or more complex introspective containers.